# Panelizer page manager in custom form

Tags: 7, forms, panels

I don't know if I am asking this question correctly or if it has already been asked elsewhere, but I thought it couldn't hurt to ask. Would it be possible to add the panelizer page manager to a custom form? Basically the node would be created first`node_save($node)`, then loaded `node_load($node)`, and then the layout change would occur through a user's selection in page manager. See image below for an idea of what I am referring to. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

[image: page manager]